# Integrating Multiple WooCommerce Site with PayPal

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I (now) have multiple websites using WordPress / WooCommerce.  Unfortunately, I can specify only 1 auto-return url in PayPal.

How do I get around this so that I can use multiple WooCommerce set-ups with 1 PayPal account?

Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is Payments Standard, the basic PayPal gateway that comes with WooCommerce.  This is limited in the way WooCommerce has it integrated, so unfortunately, you won't be able to make it work without some customization.

Another option, though, is to install [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) and use that instead.  You would setup the Express Checkout, which does not rely on the return URL set in your PayPal profile.  Instead, it works dynamically with whatever URL the site is running on.  There are also lots of other benefits to Express Checkout as well which you can see in the plugin details / videos.

The plugin is free and Express Checkout with PayPal is free as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've made multiple Woocommerce websites work with a single PayPal business account using the receiver email option found under
Woocommerce>Checkout>PayPal
Make sure it is set to your main email for paypal.

I have also checked Enable PayPal standard.

Payment action should be set to capture.

If you are selling downloadable products, make sure you check "Grant access to downloadable products after payment" on the Products>Downloadable tab